# Abort the Sammy.RenderContext sequence of requests when I switch to another route?

Tags: javascript, sammy.js

I have a route that calls a series of load requests in a following fashion:

```
this                                                       
  .load('/url/to/template.html')
  .then(function(html) {                                                                                         

  })                                                                  
  .load('/url/to/partial/template.html')
  .then(function(html) {

  })                                                                  
  .load('/url/to/partial/template.html')    
  .then(function(html) {

  })                                                                  
  .load('/url/to/json', {json: true})   
  .then(function(data){                                               

  });
```

Is there a way to abort these request if I switch to another route?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way built in to Sammy to abort async requests if you switch to another route. The best you can do is abort processing the data loaded by an async request after it returns to the callback. How I would go about that is using a global object, which would allow you to check if it changed since you started running the code. It would look something like this:

```
window.currentRoute = null;
Sammy.get('#/some/path/here', function() {
    // This should be an object because that way we can take advantage of
    // Reference Type equality. However, it doesn't matter what is put in
    // here, and could easily just be "new Object()".
    var localCurrentRoute = {
        'currentPath': '#/some/path/here'
    };
    // If you don't always want to override the current route, put some logic
    // before this assignment.
    window.currentRoute = localCurrentRoute;
    this.load('/url/to/template.html').then(function(html) {                                                                                         
        // Check if the route is the same object as what we started with, and
        // if not, abort further processing of this resource.
        if(window.currentRoute !== localCurrentRoute) {
            return;
        }
        // ... do stuff here
    });
});
```

Using this code, whenever you load a new route, you should be changing the object that the global is pointing to. Using reference type equality, if the route isn't what we started with, we know that the route has changed underneath us and the async load().then() methods will not process their data further. This gets around most issues with async loading (that being the context underneath it changing), however, and I find is usually good enough for most purposes.

However, this does not stop the loading of data, which cannot be done with Sammy by default. If you have particularly long running requests, you might look into an alternative async library, and the code above would have to be modified to store a reference to each async call that is aborted whenever a new route is loaded. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader to do with their favorite library.

Answer (score 0):

there is no build in option, but i made a little workaround.
in **sammy.js** :

```js
(function ($) {

var Sammy,
     currentXhr = null //Added this var

....

// added this method to abort ajax call 
abort: function () {
          if (currentXhr) {
              currentXhr.abort();
              currentXhr = null;
          }
      },
      
load: function (location, options, callback) {
                var context = this;
                return this.then(function () {
                    ....
                     this.wait();
                     
                     //abort any current call
                     this.abort(); //Added this row
                     
                     currentXhr = $.ajax($.extend({ //added 'currentXhr ='
                     ...
```